# Python - How to import a class from a different directory for unit testing

Tags: python-2.7

This question has been asked a hundred times, but every solution I've seen does not work for me, and I'm getting extremely frustrated so here's 101.

Given the project directory:

```
project/
  src/
    __init__.py
    student.py
  test/
    __init__.py
    student_test.py
```

My student.py file:

```
class Student:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
   self.full_name = name
   self.age = age
```

My student_test.py file:

```
from nose.tools import *
import src
from src import Student

def test_basic():
  print "I RAN!"

def test_student():
  s = Student("Steve", 42)
  assert s.age == 42
```

I get the following errors:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (cannot import name Student)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    from src import Student
ImportError: cannot import name Student
```

I've tried variations of the import yada yada and adding the `src`directory to path, but nothing seems to work here. WTF am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you are tied to this directory structure, here is one solution to get your test to run.

```
from nose.tools import *
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/Users/daino3/Workspace/student-project/src') # the absolute path of /src directory
from student import Student

def test_basic():
  print "I RAN!"

def test_student():
  s = Student("Steve", 42)
  assert s.age == 42

test_basic()
test_student()
```

Alternatively, place your test in the same directory as the source, then simply `from student import Student`.